# How to convert a 'Y' or 'N' Value to a boolean value using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, list, datatable, enumerable

I have this function of mine which selects all room types from the database, I am converting values from a data table to a generic list to optimize the speed of the system that i am creating my problem is how to covert each of the values stored for the field isActive which has a value from the database of "Active"/"Inactive" which i had to convert to a boolean value in C#.net 4.0 can you guys please help me with this?.

```
         internal static List<RoomType> FetchRoomTypeList()
         {
             List<RoomType> roomTypes = new List<RoomType>();
             SqlCommand commRoomTypeSelector = ConnectionManager.MainConnection.CreateCommand();
             commRoomTypeSelector.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             commRoomTypeSelector.CommandText = "Rooms.asp_RMS_RoomTypeList_Select";
             SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(commRoomTypeSelector);
             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
             da.Fill(ds);
             roomTypes = (from rt in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                          select new RoomType
                          {
                              RoomTypeID = rt.Field<int>("RoomTypeID"),
                              RoomTypeName = rt.Field<string>("RoomType"),
                              LastEditDate = rt.Field<DateTime>("LastEditDate"),
                              LastEditUser = rt.Field<string>("LastEditUser"),
                              IsActive = rt.Field<string>("IsActive") == "Active"
                          }
                         ).ToList();

             return roomTypes;
         }
```

The line below does not return true values, insted it always return false values

```
IsActive = rt.Field<string>("IsActive") == "Active"
```

REQUESTED SAMPLE DATA:

[image]

Comment: Useless use of `condition? true: false` spotted.

Comment: Can you give a good suggestion buddy :(

Comment: if i see `== false` it makes sense to me. But otherwise == true and ?true:false (or vice versa) makes me annoyed. Its always a bad flag for me

Comment: Yeah you're right buddy.. id revised the sample

Comment: Are you testing for "Y" / "N" like your title implies, or "Active" / "InActive" like your question shows?

Comment: Some sample data rows please, showing the IsActive value as seen in the database.

Comment: Pepito we had revised the insertion of records in our application that the reason why my title is different. Will I've just uploaded a sample row by the way its already solved thanks to adrift(He's very good at LINQ) Thanks again buddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps there are spaces in the field? Try `rt.Field<string>("IsActive").Trim()`.

---

Ok, if you check `rt.Field<string>("IsActive")` and it is definitely a single character with a UTF8 value of 89 (`'Y'`) or 121 (`'y'`) then my next guess is that it's the property.

Is `RoomType.IsActive` an automatic property?  If not, can you make sure the getter and setter are correct?

And if that's not it, and at `return roomTypes;` everything looks ok, then your values are being changed somewhere up the call stack.

Comment: If you debug and set a breakpoint there, what is the value of `rt.Field<string>("IsActive")`?

Comment: Yes I Did that buddy.. I'm pretty sure there were no spaces there.

Comment: Ok, I'm stumped.  If you are sure the value is `y` or `Y`, your code should work (regardless of the fact that a conditional is not needed).  Either that value is not `y` / `Y` when you expect it to be, or its being modified later.  Last idea I have is to check the actual code value of the character returned.  While debugging, if you add a watch for `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rt.Field<string>("IsActive").ToCharArray())` does it show a `byte[]` with 1 entry with a value of `89` or `121`?

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer with my last guess.  Could be the `RoomType.IsActive` property...

Comment: Buddy.. You're right it was being changed by my class after it was initialized. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
IsActive = rt.Field<string>("IsActive").Trim().ToUpper().Equals("Y")
```

There is no need to specify true false.

Comment: IsActive buddy is a boolean value.. :(

Comment: Equals returns true or false :)

Comment: Allan, you're being very confusing: Your original post clearly shows that you're testing the IsActive property against "Active", meaning it's a string, but now you're saying it's a boolean???  Could you please provide a few sample rows from the database for us to look at?

Comment: Aha.. Muhammad Addel Zahid Sorry Just a newbie here :) , @naveen I had minimized the code without the use of this code only... IsActive = rt.Field<string>("IsActive") == "Active" The error occurs in the class that my teammate provided :) By the way i really appreciate the help and i've solve it already thanks :)